# Call python function from c++ with passing array data (using boost python/numpy)

Tags: python, c++, boost

I'd like to call python function from c++ with passing array data (c++ to python function)
To do this, I use boost python and boost numpy.

I tried it with various ways, but I still have a problem.
I faced error message, "py_state" is not defined.

Could you please let me know your advice.

p::exec("act = agent.get_action(py_state)", main_namespace);

Error ----------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  NameError: name 'py_state' is not defined

---

c++ code

```
int main()
{
     setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);
     Py_Initialize();
     np::initialize();
     PyRun_SimpleString("#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-");        
     p::object main_module = p::import("__main__");
     p::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");
     p::object print = p::import("__main__").attr("__builtins__").attr("print");
     p::exec("import sys", main_namespace);
     p::exec("import neural_net as nn", main_namespace);

                   ..... c++ code

     p::exec("agent = nn.neural_net(22,3)", main_namespace);
     np::ndarray py_state = np::from_data(input_state, np::dtype::get_builtin<double>(), p::make_tuple(22), p::make_tuple(sizeof(double)), p::object());        

     p::object temp_stat = py_state;
     print(py_state);

     p::exec("act = agent.get_action(py_state)", main_namespace);
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^  Here is error

  }
```

Pythion code  (Just for reference)

```
 import sys
 import gym
 import pylab
 import numpy as np
 from keras.layers import Dense
 from keras.models import Sequential
 from keras.optimizers import Adam
 from keras import backend as K

 EPISODES = 1000


 # 카트폴 예제에서의 액터-크리틱(A2C) 에이전트
 class neural_net:
 def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
         self.render = False
         self.load_model = False
    # 상태와 행동의 크기 정의
    self.state_size = state_size
    self.action_size = action_size
    self.value_size = 1

    # 액터-크리틱 하이퍼파라미터
    self.discount_factor = 0.99
    self.actor_lr = 0.001
    self.critic_lr = 0.005

    # 정책신경망과 가치신경망 생성
    self.actor = self.build_actor()
    self.critic = self.build_critic()
    self.actor_updater = self.actor_optimizer()
    self.critic_updater = self.critic_optimizer()
#print("Ran __init__ of neural_net")

    if self.load_model:
        self.actor.load_weights("./save_model/cartpole_actor_trained.h5")
        self.critic.load_weights("./save_model/cartpole_critic_trained.h5")

# actor: 상태를 받아 각 행동의 확률을 계산
def build_actor(self):
    actor = Sequential()
    actor.add(Dense(24, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu',
                    kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    actor.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='softmax',
                    kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    actor.summary()
    return actor

# critic: 상태를 받아서 상태의 가치를 계산
def build_critic(self):
    critic = Sequential()
    critic.add(Dense(24, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu',
                     kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    critic.add(Dense(24, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu',
                     kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    critic.add(Dense(self.value_size, activation='linear',
                     kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    critic.summary()
    return critic

# 정책신경망의 출력을 받아 확률적으로 행동을 선택
def get_action(self, state):
    policy = self.actor.predict(state, batch_size=1).flatten()
    print(state, policy)
    return np.random.choice(self.action_size, 1, p=policy)[0]

# 정책신경망을 업데이트하는 함수
def actor_optimizer(self):
    action = K.placeholder(shape=[None, self.action_size])
    advantage = K.placeholder(shape=[None, ])

    action_prob = K.sum(action * self.actor.output, axis=1)
    cross_entropy = K.log(action_prob) * advantage
    loss = -K.sum(cross_entropy)

    optimizer = Adam(lr=self.actor_lr)
    updates = optimizer.get_updates(self.actor.trainable_weights, [], loss)
    train = K.function([self.actor.input, action, advantage], [],
                       updates=updates)
    return train

# 가치신경망을 업데이트하는 함수
def critic_optimizer(self):
    target = K.placeholder(shape=[None, ])

    loss = K.mean(K.square(target - self.critic.output))

    optimizer = Adam(lr=self.critic_lr)
    updates = optimizer.get_updates(self.critic.trainable_weights, [], loss)
    train = K.function([self.critic.input, target], [], updates=updates)

    return train

# 각 타임스텝마다 정책신경망과 가치신경망을 업데이트
def train_model(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
    value = self.critic.predict(state)[0]
    next_value = self.critic.predict(next_state)[0]

    act = np.zeros([1, self.action_size])
    act[0][action] = 1

    # 벨만 기대 방정식를 이용한 어드벤티지와 업데이트 타깃
    if done:
        advantage = reward - value
        target = [reward]
    else:
        advantage = (reward + self.discount_factor * next_value) - value
        target = reward + self.discount_factor * next_value

    self.actor_updater([state, act, advantage])
    self.critic_updater([state, target])


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     # CartPole-v1 환경, 최대 타임스텝 수가 500
     env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
     # 환경으로부터 상태와 행동의 크기를 받아옴
state_size = env.observation_space.shape[0]
action_size = env.action_space.n

# 액터-크리틱(A2C) 에이전트 생성
agent = neural_net(state_size, action_size)

scores, episodes = [], []

for e in range(EPISODES):
    done = False
    score = 0
    state = env.reset()
    state = np.reshape(state, [1, state_size])

    while not done:
        if agent.render:
            env.render()

        action = agent.get_action(state)
        next_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        next_state = np.reshape(next_state, [1, state_size])
        # 에피소드가 중간에 끝나면 -100 보상
        reward = reward if not done or score == 499 else -100

        agent.train_model(state, action, reward, next_state, done)

        score += reward
        state = next_state

        if done:
            # 에피소드마다 학습 결과 출력
            score = score if score == 500.0 else score + 100
            scores.append(score)
            episodes.append(e)
            pylab.plot(episodes, scores, 'b')
            pylab.savefig("./save_graph/cartpole_a2c.png")
            print("episode:", e, "  score:", score)

            # 이전 10개 에피소드의 점수 평균이 490보다 크면 학습 중단
            if np.mean(scores[-min(10, len(scores)):]) > 490:
                agent.actor.save_weights("./save_model/cartpole_actor.h5")
                agent.critic.save_weights(
                    "./save_model/cartpole_critic.h5")
                sys.exit()
```